# Merge [qtp] questions into [hp-uft]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

QTP is *QuickTest Professional*, test automation software which was built by Mercury Interactive. Mercury was sold to [HP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Inc.), who repackaged the tool as Unified Functional Tester.

Pretty much all QTP questions apply to UFT and vice versa, so much so they are generally all tagged with both.

[qtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtp) has more questions, but is the "older" version of the software, so can we merge the questions from [qtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtp) into [hp-uft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hp-uft) and then stop using the [qtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtp) tag?